# ラジオボタンを使う(PHP)

Tags: php

ラジオボタンを作ってますが、31行目がエラー表示されます。
綴りも合ってますし、 全角も入ってないです。
何が問題だと思われますか。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ラジオボタン</title>
    <link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php
            require_once("util.php");
            //文字エンコードの検証
            if (!cken($_POST)) {
                $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
                $err = "Encoding Error! The expected encoding is " . $encoding;
                // エラーメッセージを出して、以下のコードを全てキャンセルする
                exit($err);
            }
            //HTMLエスケープ(XSS対策)
            $_POST = es($_POST);
        ?>

        <?php
            //エラーを入れる配列
            $error = [];
            //POSTされた性別を取り出す
            if (isSet($_POST[ "sex" ])) {
                //性別かどうか確認する
                $sexValue = [ "男性","女性" ];
                //$sexValueに含まれている値ならばtrue
                $isSex = in_array($_POST[ "sex" ], $sexValues);
                if ($isSex) {
                    //選択されている値を取り出す
                    $sex = $_POST[ "sex" ];
                } else {
                    $sex = "error";
                    $error[] = "「性別」に入力エラーがありました。";
                }
            } else {
                //POSTされた値がない時
                $isSex = false;
                $sex = "男性";
            }
            //POSTされた結婚を取り出す
            if (isSet($_POST[ "marriage" ] )) {
                //結婚かどうか確認する
                $marriageValues = [ "独身" , "既婚" , "同棲中" ];
                // $marriageValuesに含まれている値ならtrue
                $isMarriage = in_array($_POST[ "marriage" ],$marriageValues);
                if ($isMarriage) {
                    //選択されている値を取り出す
                    $marriage = $_POST[ "marriage" ];
                } else {
                    $marriage = "error";
                    $error[] = "「結婚」に入力エラーがありました。";
                }
            } else {
                //POSTされた値がない時
                $isMarriage = false;
                $marriage = "独身";
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            //初期値でチェックするかどうか
            function checked($value, $question) {
                if (is_array($question)) {
                    //配列の時、値が含まれていればtrue
                    $isChecked = in_array($value, $question);
                } else {
                    //配列ではない時、値が一致すればtrue
                    $isChecked = ($value===$question);
                }

                if ($isChecked) {
                    //チェックする
                    echo "checked";
                } else {
                    echo "";
                }
            }    
        ?>   

        <form method="POST" action="<?php echo es($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">         
            <ul>
                <li><span>性別:</span>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="男性" <?php checked("男性",$sex); ?>>男性</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="sex" value="女性" <?php checked("女性",$sex); ?>>女性</label>
                </li>
                <li><span>結婚:</span>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="marriage" value="独身" <?php checked("独身",$marriage); ?>>独身</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="marriage" value="既婚" <?php checked("既婚",$marriage); ?>>既婚</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="marriage" value="同棲中" <?php checked("同棲中",$marriage); ?>>同棲中</label>
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="送信する" ></li>
            </ul>
        </form>       

        <?php
            //性別と結婚が受信されていれば結果を表示する
            $isSubmited = $isSex && $isMarriage;
            if ($isSubmited) {
                echo "<HR>";
                echo "あなたは「{$sex}、{$marriage}」です。";
            }
        ?>
        <?php
            //エラー表示
            if (count($error)>0) {
                echo "<HR>";
                //値を"<br>"で連結して表示する
                echo '<span class="error">' , implode("<br>",$error), '</span>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

エラーコード

```
[30-Jul-2018 03:00:29 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: sexValues in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/profile.php on line 31
[30-Jul-2018 03:00:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/profile.php on line 31
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: う〜ん、エラーメッセージにはっきりと表示されていますが、`s` が余計なんじゃないでしょうか。。。

Answer (score 1):

31行目の$sexVlue"s"の"s"を抜いて解決できました。
ありがとうございます。